# Split a categorical numpy array based on conditional value

Tags: arrays, python-3.x, numpy

I'm trying to split a categorical numpy array using based on a conditional value such that the length of split sub-arrays is equal to the conditional value.

For instance, I have a categorical numpy array-like below and I want to split the numpy array based on conditional value like below

```
import numpy as np

x = np.array(['Horses', 'Cats', 'Dogs'])

conditional_value = 1
```

which eventually should result in a numpy array like below:

```
Expected Output :

array([['Horses'],
       ['Cats'],
       ['Dogs']], dtype='<U6')
```

I tried with using `np.split` but the result is something that was not expected.

```
import numpy as np

x = np.array(['Horses', 'Cats', 'Dogs'])

np.split(x, 1)

Actual Output : [array(['Horses', 'Cats', 'Dogs'], dtype='<U6')]
```

What is other way to split the above numpy array such that length of each sub-array is equal to conditional value ?

Comment: what if `conditional_value = 2` ?

Comment: I think that would throw an error on the example code, because array is of 1-dimension, and by assigning value to 2 we are adding another dimension.

Answer (score 1):

#### Use `np.reshape` to change the split the array in the way that you want

```
import numpy as np

x = np.array(['Horses', 'Cats', 'Dogs'])

np.reshape(x, [3,1])
```

#### For a more general case of `conditional_value`

```
import numpy as np

x = np.array(['Horses', 'Cats', 'Dogs','Owls'])
conditional_value = 2

np.reshape(x, [len(x)//conditional_value,conditional_value])
```